# Matplot lib image properties in web (Django)

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, graph, matplotlib-widget

I'd like to output the image to the web created in matplotlib having the very same functionality like it has on desktop when you run the `image.show()`, for example scaling, moving along the plot more thoroughly.

I've checked out #stack and got old post only offering static images or gif or `matplotlib.animate()`

I aslo had a look at matplotlib widgets, but those are for desktop GUI only as far as I can see.

Please share some experience or ideas regarding how can I achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib is a server side library so you cannot do anything on the client side like that.

The closest you can come is to either use [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/) (mpld3 works by converting a matplotlib graph into the html/js that a d3 js graph would need to render) or a different client side library that plots points.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you very much. Have you tried it yourself? Are there any viable examples of django/mpld3 integrated?

Comment: @Aleks_Saint - I created a proof of concept for our application in mpld3 but we decided that our use case didn't require it in the end. The linked docs have [lots of examples](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of serving pure matplotlib to the web is using a [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org).

Other than that, you may want to look at specific libraries like *Plotly* or *bokeh*.

Comment: I've checked them out, however the mpld3 looks more of what I need. Thank you!

Comment: I once started using mpld3 and after a while realized that bokeh was much better suited, since it can be run dynamically on a server as well as statically served on the webpage. At the end it all depends on the application.

Comment: checked out bokeh more thoroughly, it looks like it is designed for pretty massive stand-alone apps, but that opens pretty interesting perspectives, I appreciate your sharing it with me, thank you!